# HttpUrlConnection issue when tablet is inactive

Tags: android

I'm having an issue on multiple devices where when the device isn't interacted with for a period of time, my HttpUrlConnection's don't operate as expected. The projects target platform is Android 4.0.3.

Below is an example of how I'm using HttpUrlConnection.

```
new AsyncRequestDTOBaseItemArray(callback).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, url);
```

The actual AsyncTask

```
public class AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem extends AsyncTask<String,String,Object> {

HttpURLConnection connection;
InputStream inStream;
IApiCallback callback;

public AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem(IApiCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
protected Object doInBackground(String... uri) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL(uri[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
        connection.addRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
        connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        connection.connect();

        String encoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
        // Determine if the stream is compressed and uncompress it if needed.
        if (encoding != null && encoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
            inStream = new GZIPInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        }  else {
            inStream = connection.getInputStream();
        }

        if (inStream != null) {
           InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inStream);
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            try {
                DTOBaseItem item = gson.fromJson(isr, DTOBaseItem.class);
                return item;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.i("AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem", "Exception");
                if (e != null && e.getMessage() != null) {
                    Log.e("AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem", e.getMessage());
                }
            } finally {
                inStream.close();                   
            }
        }   

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.i("AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem", "Socket Timeout occured");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i("AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem","IOException");

        if (e != null && e.getMessage() != null) {
            Log.i("AsyncRequestDTOBaseItem",e.getMessage());
        }

    } finally {
        if (connection != null)
            connection.disconnect();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
    callback.Execute(result);
}
}
```

I don't see any issues with the above code unless the device has been inactive. When the device has been inactive the last code line that executes is

```
String encoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
```

I've also gone into the wifi settings and made sure that my wifi doesn't sleep. I thought at first it might be that the wifi reconnecting was creating this issue.

Comment: Just as a side remark: [HttpUrlConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) handles gzip compression transparently if it is available. In general, you don't need to do it yourself?

Comment: I didn't know that. That'll trim a few lines. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue may have been the server not sending data back.

I added **connection.setReadTimeout(5000);** and now the issue seems to have gone away.